# Azure Devops: chromedriver is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run Automation Tests on Azure Devops using [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). For that I am following below steps:

1. `npm install -g chromedriver` This works fine
2. `chromedriver -v` This works fine and gives `ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689})`
3. But when I run maven command, for ex: `mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke" -e` then it gives below error.

   ```
   2020-10-06T12:34:50.0688871Z Oct 06, 2020 12:34:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
   2020-10-06T12:34:50.0689959Z SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: 
   Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: 
   Cannot run program "G:\a\..\..\_tool\node\..\..\x64\chromedriver" (in directory "."):
   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application)
   ```
4. Node version is v10.22.1
5. NPM version is 6.14.6
6. OS name: "windows server 2016", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows". It is VM and ADO Agent

Answer (score 0):

There a few possible causes for the "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" message including: the pathname for the application is incorrect or the file is a 32 bit executable, but for some reason it is trying to load a 64 bit DLL.

`npm install -g chromedriver` It will use a global location instead of install chromedriver under the local folder, you can use the cmd `npm install chromedriver` and check the log then we can get the path.

If we are using `npm install -g` to install the program. On Windows the path could be `C:\Users\YOU\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`, and according to the log, we can see that it run the program under `G:\a\..\..\_tool\node\..\..\x64\chromedriver`

Comment: Still the same error `2020-10-07T09:01:43.8080408Z Oct 07, 2020 9:01:43 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
2020-10-07T09:01:43.8100281Z SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "G:\a\prd2_a1\_tool\node\1x.xx.x\x64\chromedriver" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application)`. I checked prevoious logs it is the same location always `"G:\a\prd2_a1\_tool\node\1x.xx.x\x64\chromedriver"`